# create file using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, file

I've a problem with this code

```
    SELECT id_order,lastname,firstname,productName,productPrice
FROM _commandes
WHERE id_order=13
INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Documents and Settings\Stagiaire\Mes documents\Document\bonDeCommandes\No13.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

When I execute it on phpMyAdmin it doesn't create file but doesn't display error either. I'm in local and I would like to create a file for each order. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to put "/" instead of "\" in the path.

Comment: You mean the \ present inside the file path?